# Hadoop headerroom miscalculation

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I tried to run a hadoop application. It is running when only on single node, but can't run on multi-node cluster.
The log file shows this error everytime before the application stops

```
2015-11-27 14:50:19,513 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:19456, vCores:-3>
2015-11-27 14:50:19,513 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
```

I searched for some solutions, they suggested to set virtual memory limits in mapred-site.xml and set the virtual memory ration in yarn-site.xml
So, I now my mapred-site.xml file currently is

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:5431</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3072m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3072m</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

And, my yarn-site.xml file is:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8035</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8050</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How many mappers and reducers are spawned for your application?

Comment: The mappers and reducers it is taking is by default.

Comment: I tried setting mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps to 1.0, but still it isn't working

Comment: That won't help. There seems to be a problem with container allocation. I have explained it in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following error occurs, because available resources for this job is "null" (Means no resources are available).

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=
```

And following error occurs, when the number of completed mappers is less than the threshold needed for starting the reducers. This value is determined by the configuration parameter: `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps` (in mapred-site.xml), which is by default set to .05 (means, reducers are not started till at least 5% of mappers are completed).

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
```

In your case, the **completedMapsForReduceSlowStart** is set to **1**.

Following piece of code determines this value:

```
//check for slow start
if (!getIsReduceStarted()) {//not set yet
  int completedMapsForReduceSlowstart = (int)Math.ceil(reduceSlowStart * 
                  totalMaps);
  if(completedMaps < completedMapsForReduceSlowstart) {
    LOG.info("Reduce slow start threshold not met. " +
          "completedMapsForReduceSlowstart " + 
        completedMapsForReduceSlowstart);
    return;
```

**It means, at least 1 mapper should have been completed (because, I guess your threshold is set to 5% and you have 20 mappers, hence 5% of 20 = 1), before reducers can start.**

**So, in your case, not even 1 mapper has completed execution.**

This indicates, there is a serious problem with your memory settings in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml. The YARN RM is unable to allocate any containers for your mappers, hence not a single mapper is running.

I have pasted my memory settings below (which work perfectly for me). Compare your settings with the settings below and apply the settings proportionally. For e.g. in my case, (yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb) / (yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb) = (9830) / (1228) = 8.

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property> <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name> <value>1228</value> </property>
<property> <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name> <value>-Xmx983m</value> </property>
<property> <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name> <value>1228</value> </property>
<property> <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name> <value>9830</value> </property>
<property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> <value>9830</value> </property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property> <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name> <value>1228</value> </property>
<property> <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name> <value>1228</value> </property>
<property> <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name> <value>-Xmx983m</value> </property>
<property> <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name> <value>-Xmx983m</value> </property>
```

Also, refer to the following blogs on tuning the YARN configuration:

1. [Tuning the Cluster for MapReduce v2 (YARN)](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html)
2. [How to Plan and Configure YARN and MapReduce 2 in HDP 2.0](http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/)

After setting your memory configurations properly, you should be able to run your job.

Comment: Thanks @Manjunath. I faced the same problem in my single node hadoop cluster and the memory config changes you suggest resolve the issue. I didn't quite follow the root cause though.
I am using hadoop version 2.7.2. Given that the problem is due the fact that the Yarn RM is unable to allocate any containers for mappers, what role does MR AppMaster, Scheduler and node manager play during a map reduce job execution? Why do need to update the memory allocation for map and reduce jobs in mapred-site.xml? Why specify both memory settings in mb and java-opts? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Andy Dufresne, glad my answer helped. Your questions are valid and I too have many doubts about this. MRAppMaster: Negotiates computes the required number of mappers and reducers and sends a request to RM for those resources. Scheduler: Does scheduling on different Node Managers based on the resource requirement. Node Manager: Each Node Manager reports its available resources to RM and allocates containers and does the actual execution of the process. Map/Reduce memory requirements are specific to each job. Bases on this, the App Master decides the number of mappers and reducers.

Comment: @Andy Dufresne The settings for mapreduce.[map | reduce].java.opts.max.heap specify the default memory allotted for mapper and reducer heap size, respectively. The mapreduce.[map| reduce].memory.mb settings specify memory allotted their containers, and the value assigned should allow overhead beyond the task heap size. So heap size should be around 80% of the total container size. In my example it is 983 MB = (.8) * (1228 MB)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So there are many components involved in the MR job execution - Node Manager (which manages the name node and data node), Resource manager, Scheduler, MR AppMaster and the individual mappers and reducers that execute the MR code respectively. These mappers and reducers are themselves instantiated in containers. Do you have a good video link that explains the recent system architecture (components) of Hadoop 2.0?

Comment: @Andy Dufresne Node Manager is responsible for just compute. It does not control Data Node. The Data Node is another entity, which manages data stored in HDFS. There are many videos in the internet which give introduction to YARN (I can't point to any particular video). I learnt by installing a one box version of Hortonworks and playing around with it. Also, there are blogs by Hortonworks and Clodera folks, which give you a nice introduction.